# sql how to get a count based on two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm pretty new to sql and I'm just wondering how I can get a count based on the values of two columns. Here's an example:

```
Sex |  age

 M  |  7

 M  |  5

 F  |  5 

 M  |  7
```

The resulting table would have an extra column that is the count of how many M or F are a certain age. So in this case it would be this:

```
Sex | age  | Count

 M  |  7   |  2

 M  |  5   |  1

 F  |  5   |  1
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a basic aggregation query. using `group by`:

```
select sex, age, count(*) as Cnt
from t
group by sex, age
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*), sex, age from table group by sex, age;
```

Comment: You answer is wrong, it just gives a column with numbers representing counts which would be useless

Comment: @tee added the columns